# How to add subtags into the CDATA section in lxml?

Tags: python, html, lxml, cdata

I am trying to wrap a text in `CDATA` as well as include tags within the `CDATA` without it being added to the text. This is an example:

```xml
<root>
<HTML_NARR><![CDATA[<html><body><pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
textsss</pre></body></html>]]></HTML_NARR>
</root
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
html = ET.SubElement(root, "HTML_NARR")
html.text = 'textsss'
html.text = ET.CDATA(html.text)
```

I have also tried this too:

```py
parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
html = ET.XML('<ROOT><![CDATA[<html><body><pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;">test</pre></body></html>]]></ROOT>', parser)
```

I will like to get just the text when I print `html.text`:

```py
print(html.text) # -> textsss
```

But right now if I `print(html.text)`, I get:

```html
<html><body><pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;">textsss</pre></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do this. `<html><body><pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;">textsss</pre></body></html>` **is** the text of the element. The whole point of CDATA sections is to make content that looks like markup be treated as plain text.

Comment: Maybe someone can help if you explain why you want this. What problem would be solved if you could get what you refer to as "just the text"?

Comment: Data is being transferred from one database to another in xml format that was the xml requirement for the text section. I will confirm if it's necessary to include the html tags within the CDATA section and if iit is; if they don't mind it being added to the text. 
But the reason why i want it, is because it was a requirement and that was the format specified. Thank you!